# ContextMenuStrip does not appear when clicking on object within a UserControl

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, contextmenustrip

I created a UserControl with a chart inside that are the same size.
In my main form I create these UserControls dynamically and I can delete or edit them using a ContextMenuStrip by right clicking.

The problem happens when I create dynamically and click on the UserControl above the chart (inside UserControl) the ContextMenuStrip does not appear, it appears only when I click on the `userform`.

I tested several alternatives to no avail. Someone would have an idea.

EDIT:

[image: Picture1]

I have a UserControl (dynamically generated that is in blue), which is contained in my main form in green. The UserControl consists of just a chart and internal codes, it has the same size as the UserControl (I moved it to exemplify).

Right-clicking on the UserControl, I open a ContextMenuStrip (which belongs to the main form) that allows you to delete, edit and copy.

However the ContextMenuStrip only appears if I click on the UserControl (gray part), if I click on the chart (yellow part) it does not appear.

EDIT2:

I use this code in the main form

```
Public Sub add_Control_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

    Try
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            Dim cms = New ContextMenuStrip

            Dim item1 = cms.Items.Add("Edit")
            item1.Tag = 1
            AddHandler item1.Click, AddressOf menuEdit

            Dim item2 = cms.Items.Add("Delete")
            item2.Tag = 2
            AddHandler item2.Click, AddressOf menuEdit

            Dim item3 = cms.Items.Add("Copy")
            item2.Tag = 3
            AddHandler item3.Click, AddressOf menuEdit

            cms.Show(sender, e.Location)

            tempControl = sender
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub menuEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Try
        Dim item = CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
        Dim selection = CInt(item.Tag)

        changedControls = True                                              'Set changed controls
        SalvarToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True                              'Set definition enable

        Select Case selection
            Case 0
                tempCopied = True
                copiedControl = tempControl
            Case 1
                callEditControl(tempControl)
            Case 3
                If MsgBox("Do you want to remove the item.", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion, "Delete") = vbOK Then
                    Me.Controls.Remove(tempControl)
                End If

        End Select

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub`
```

Comment: Multiple pictures showing when it works and doesn't work would go a long way in helping you figure it out.

Comment: Screenshots would definitely help and more specific details about exactly what you have with regards to what controls have been placed where and what code is supposed to get executed when. As it stands, your explanation is just too vague.

Comment: Sorry, I will improve the question

Comment: Maybe use a [ContextMenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip) (or are you already? You're not using exactly a ToolStrip, right?), assigned to the Chart control. You may have noticed that Controls have a `ContexMenuStrip` property.

Comment: Why are you making that ContextMenuStrip dynamically if it doesn't change?  Create it at design-time.  When you create instances of your UserControl, assign it to the UserControl's [ContextMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenu?view=netframework-4.8) property.  It's currently unclear if the chart you're using can also have this done to it as well.

Comment: @Idle_Mind [ContextMenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenustrip?view=netframework-4.8)